# JQuery Autocomplete - onscreen keyboard on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, autocomplete

i am building a simple autocomplete lookup, webpage i have got this working on a desktop/laptop, but when i try it on a mobile/tablet im having an issue when the user types in a search query the result list beneath the search bar is covered by the onscreen keyboard.

Is there away to dismiss the keyboard when the result is displayed or will i have to move the search bar to the top of the screen and limit the results displayed so they are not covered by the onscreen keyboard, here is what i am using at the moment for my autocomplete text field.

```
        $('#autoComp').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data:{
                query: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                if(data.length == 0){               
                    data.push({
                            label: "Name not Found",
                            value: 0
                            });
                    response(data);
                }else{
                     response(
                        $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            var code = item.split("|");
                            return {
                                label: code[0] + " - " + code[1],
                                value: code[0],
                                data : item
                            }
                        })
                        );
                }
            }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,            
        minLength: 4,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            if(ui.item.value == "Name not Found"){
                hideAutoComplete();
                $('#name').val($('#autoComp').val());
                setTimeout(function(){
                    selectParty();
                }, 800);
            }else{
                hideAutoComplete();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    selectParty();
                }, 800);
                var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
                $('#name').val(names[0]);
                $('#village').val(names[1]);    
            }
        }           
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?